# Firebase GeoFire using a FirebaseRecylerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui, geofire

How do I populate a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter using Key Values obtained after perfoming a Geoquery on Firebase?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements {

private RecyclerView myLocationAds;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MyAds, MyLocAdsViewHolder> myLocAdsAdapter;
private DatabaseReference myLocRefernce;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private double mLatitudeText;
private double mLongitudeText;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private Location location;
private GeoFire geoFire;
private GeoQuery geoQuery;
GeoLocation center;
```

Declarations

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDatabaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    mDatabaseUser.keepSynced(true);
    geoFire = new GeoFire(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("geofire"));

}
```

Intialize my RecyclerView

```
private void intializeScreen() {
    myLocationAds = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myLocationAds);
    myLocationAds.setHasFixedSize(true);
    myLocationAds.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
    myLocRefernce = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.Adverts);
    myLocRefernce.keepSynced(true);
    setUpAdapter();
    myLocationAds.setAdapter(myLocAdsAdapter);


}
```

Here's My FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

```
private void setUpAdapter() {
    myLocAdsAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MyAds, MyLocAdsViewHolder>(
            MyAds.class,
            R.layout.adverts_row,
            MyLocAdsViewHolder.class,
            myLocRefernce

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(MyLocAdsViewHolder myLocAdsViewHolder, MyAds myAds, int position) {
            final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();

            myLocAdsViewHolder.setAdImageV(getApplicationContext(),myAds.getImageUrl());
            myLocAdsViewHolder.setAdheadln(myAds.getAdheader());
            myLocAdsViewHolder.setAdDescp(myAds.getAdDesciption());
            myLocAdsViewHolder.setViewN(myAds.getViews());
            myLocAdsViewHolder.setComment(myAds.getNumComments());
            myLocAdsViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent adDisplay = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AdvertDisplay.class);
                    adDisplay.putExtra("Ad_data", post_key);
                    startActivity(adDisplay);
```

} });}};}

Here's My Geoquery That Gives an Output of keys within my Location Range

```
private void startGeoQuery() {
    double radius = 0.5;
    geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(center, radius);
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String s, GeoLocation geoLocation) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Key " + s + " entered the search area at [" + geoLocation.latitude + "," + geoLocation.longitude + "]");
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,geoLocation.latitude+" "+geoLocation.longitude+" ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            DatabaseReference mDatabasePost = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Constants.Adverts);
            mDatabasePost.keepSynced(true);
            mDatabasePost.child(s).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // I  add the deal only if it doesn't exist already in the adapter
                    String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, key,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyMoved(String s, GeoLocation geoLocation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });}}
```

How do I populate the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` with ONLY those keys within my Location Range?